# How to apply texture to a part of a sphere

Tags: opengl

I am trying to put a texture in only a part of a sphere.
I have a sphere representing the earth with its topography and a terrain texture for a part of the globe, say satellite map for Italy.
I want to show that terrain over the part of the sphere where Italy is.

I'm creating my sphere drawing a set of triangle strips.
As far as I understand, if I want to use a texture I need to specify a texture coord for each vertex (glTexCoord2*). But I do not have a valid texture for all of them.
So how do I tell OpenGL to skip texture for those vertexes?

Comment: Do you have only one texture for the sphere or do you want to combine multiple images (e.g. one generic earth texture and top-layers for more detail)?

Comment: you want to put a texture only small part of sphere drawn from set of triangle strips or on whole sphere.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you have two textures or a color attribute for the remainder of the sphere ("not Italy").

The easiest way to do this would be to create a texture that covers the whole sphere, but use the alpha channel. For example, use `alpha=1` for "not italy" and `alpha=0` for "italy". Then you could do something like this in your fragment shader (pseudo-code, I did not test anything):

```
...
uniform sampler2D extra_texture;
in vec2 texture_coords;
out vec3 final_color;
...
void main() {
    ...
    // Assume color1 to be the base color for the sphere, no matter how you get it (attribute/texture), it has at least 3 components.
    vec4 color2 = texture(extra_texture, texture_coords);
    final_color = mix(vec3(color2), vec3(color1), color2.a);
}
```

The colors in mix are combined as follows, `mix(x,y,a) = x*(1-a)+y*a`, this is done component wise for vectors. So you can see that if `alpha=1` ("not Italy"), `color1` will be picked, and vice versa for `alpha=0`.

You could extend this to multiple layers using texture arrays or something similar, but I'd keep it simple 2-layer to begin with.

Comment: thanks killianDS for your reply. So as far as I understand you suggest to manually set the color for each vertex as a combination of the texture color and the color of the base sphere. If there is no other way to specify that a texture should be mapped only to a portion of the 3D object, it seems to me a good solution. Thanks again

Comment: It's not completely manual, you apply two separately created textures. The other solution would be to draw a part of the sphere (the one where italy resides) seperately, but that would likely be more complex. You could also try to mess with "invalid" texture coordinates, but in the end, you do likely need something like I proposed because odds are fairly high you'll have to combine two colors anyway.